# Apps not loading properly

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have installed SharePoint 2013 on a single server farm. SSL is implemented and working fine. I tried installing an app and it got installed successfully. But when we are going to the app it does not load the js/css I tried to inspect the page and found Internal server error on all the js and css scripts.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you checked the relative URL's of the file?

Comment: yes the app url configuration is all file html is loading and these apps I got from sharepoint store

Comment: once you install the app it should ask for trusting it, other wise you have to go and make it trusted app so that app works fine may be this also could be issue.

Comment: Yes I have marked it trusted

Comment: No help :( in such large community